# Entity framework database differences

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm

I must have changed something that is causing an exception in the Entity Framework. I'm not sure what it was though, but I'm guessing somehow my classes are out of line with my DB. Is there a way to figure out exactly what doesn't line up?

Here is the exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information:
The model backing the 'SomethingContext' context has changed since
the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to
update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).
```

Here is the line of code:

```
var results = db.Table.Where(x => !x.IsBool);
```

Comment: You fetched the element from one context but tried to add it to another?

Comment: no, i was just querying a table. ill add an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, your classes aren't matching the schema in the database.  Do you have Code First Migrations enabled on your database? (if not, see the section on enabling migrations in the link in the exception text you provided)  If you generate a new migration (`add-migration [Name]` from the package manager console), you'll get some code generated that'll show you exactly what changes are necessary to the database to bring it up to match your code.  You don't need to actually apply the migration to the database if you don't want to (just don't run `update-database` and make sure auto-migration is turned off if you're going to try to run your application) and you can easily just delete the migration from your codebase if you're only interested in knowing what the discrepancies are.

Comment: i tried this, but it didnt tell me what i was expecting at all. it seemed to list a bunch of stuff that i definitely havent edited. any other ideas?

Comment: A few immediate thoughts: Is the stuff listed in the migration Up method an accurate reflection of your current code model? Did you target the right database/context when you created the migration? If you originally created your database with a different initialiser type, you might need to delete the row it's put in the migrations table in the database before you enable migrations. It's a little difficult to suggest much more without knowing what kind of discrepancies you're seeing in the migration. Hope some of this helps!

Comment: Another simple but potentially painful option you could try if migrations aren't working for you - retarget your application at a new database, run it and see what EF generates and then compare with your existing database.

Comment: i eventually figured out what was wrong. it seems a lot of tables were dropped on the clr side, so when i ran the migration it had a bunch of `drop` method calls. this confused me because i hadn't removed anything (someone did awhile back though), but i now understand that for every table in the db, there needs to be a corresponding clr class. i didnt spend too much time thinking about the drops because i imagined that entity would still work even if there were missing clr classes, but not if there were clr classes but no corresponding tables. obviously though, my assumption was wrong. thanks!

Comment: Glad you sorted it. :-)